# drawing video on canvas exactly the same

Tags: javascript, canvas, video

trying to draw the video element to canvas exactly how it is but the video in canvas is zoomed in :

```
<canvas></canvas>
<video autoplay="true"></video>
<script>
    let video = document.querySelector("video")
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true})
        .then((stream) => {
            video.srcObject = stream
        })
    canvasWidth = 0
    canvasHeight= 0
    video.addEventListener("playing", () => {
        canvasWidth = video.videoWidth
        canvasHeight = video.videoHeight
        canvas = document.querySelector("canvas")
        canvas.style.width = canvasWidth+"px"
        canvas.style.height = canvasHeight+"px"
        function draw() {
            let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
            ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvasWidth,canvasHeight, 0, 0 ,canvasWidth, canvasHeight)
            setTimeout(draw, 1)
        }

        setTimeout(() =>{
            draw()
        }, 1000);
    })


</script>
```

there is the picture of what it renders in browser :

[image]

Comment: You need to set the _actual_ width and height of your canvas to that of the video. If you are just _formatting_ the canvas element via the CSS properties width and height, then you are just _scaling_ your canvas.

Comment: I want to draw the video into canvas exactly without knowing what demintions will be video element in browser of user either phone or pc, I need to specify way to dynamicaly set width and height without setting it in canvas html tag, because I dont know what video element dementions will be, however setting it into canvas element works as you said

Comment: I trying to set the width and height of canvas in js with .style and without pre set it in canvas element to dynamically set to width and height of video tag after its played

Comment: You can still _scale_ your canvas via CSS, if you need it to fit on a different screen size. But the actual width and height must match those of the actual video dimensions, for it to get drawn onto the canvas properly in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you've missed to set the `canvas`'s width and height getting from the `video` element in a proper way.

```js
const video = document.querySelector("#vid");
const ctx = document.querySelector("#cvs").getContext("2d");
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true}).then((stream) => video.srcObject = stream);

function draw() {
  ctx.canvas.width = video.clientWidth;
  ctx.canvas.height = video.clientHeight;
  ctx.drawImage(video, 0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
video.addEventListener("playing", draw);
```

```html
<canvas id="cvs"></canvas>
<video id="vid" autoplay="true"></video>
```

Comment: You can remove the `width` and `height` attributes from `video` element as well.

Comment: well works this what i was trying to do now checking with my code to find my mistake thnaks

Comment: @ShahnawazHossan please avoid using sentences like *"Try this:"*, *"This should do it"*, or *"I think this is what you wanted:"* - rather explain shortly your changes.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan, thanks for the advice. I've updated this.

Comment: Why do you have `canvasWidth = 0`

Comment: Actually, I've not used `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` here. I took this code from who asked the question, I didn't remove it. Removed these from the answer.

Comment: Don't use `setTimeout(draw, 1)` use the preferred `requestAnimationFrame(draw);`